# Referring to questions

Tags: grammar

What is the appropriate way to refer to a question in a sentence? e.g. The question, is that true? is a bad one. The question, which is higher? is better than which is nearer?.

Answer (score 4):

Put quotation marks around the question. Usually, quotes indicate an actually quotation - something a person says. This is sort of a hypothetical quotation - something one might say. Put the question "Which is higher?" in quotes, like that.